# to print nth line after a matched string from a text using python

Tags: python-3.x, text-processing

I've below text and i want to print the 7th line after the string: `XXXXXXXX`

```
text = """XXXXXXXX
ABC
XYZ
Today
Yesterday
Daily Price Change
Hello
4,462
4,398"""
```

Expected output:

```
4,462
```

Most of the answers on web is using the text file, I'm trying to check using `if "XXXXXXXX" in text:`, but unable to proceed further.

Many thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Something like https://ideone.com/K2TGJK?

Comment: one can also try `text.split('\n')[7]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to wasifs answer would be using pythons `string.splitlines()` to split a multiline string to lines, something like this would work too:

```
text = """XXXXXXXX
ABC
XYZ
Today
Yesterday
Daily Price Change
Hello
4,462
4,398"""
text = text.splitlines()
c= 0 
for elem in text:
    if elem == "XXXXXXXX":
        print (text[c+7])
    c += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re` module

```
import re
s='the string'
s=re.sub(r'^.*?xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx',s)
print(s.split("\n")[6])
```